# Python Scrapy not giving desired output

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website using python Scrapy. The xpath expressions give required output when run from the scrapy shell but not when run from the spider. There is no error returned but DEBUG Crawled (200). Here is my code:-

```
 import scrapy
 import logging
 from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
 from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
 class amazon(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "automate"
 start_urls = ['http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/']
 def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//div/a[contains(@class,"tag-link-1942 tag-link-position-3")]/@href'):
        url = href.extract()    
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item2)
def parse_item2(self, response):
for url in response.xpath('//div/article/header/h2/a/@href'):
        yield 
        {
            'link': url.extract(),
        }
    next_page_url = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "wp-pagenavi")]/a[contains(@class, "page larger")]/@href')
    if next_page_url is not None:
        yield 
        {
            scrapy.Request(next_page_url.extract_first(), callback=self.parse_item2)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation in your script is somewhat confusing. If I have correctly interpreted it, I find it's lacking the output.
The following code works for me and shows the title of the articles, maybe it can help you:

```
import scrapy
import logging
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class amazon(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "automate"
    start_urls = ['http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/']

    def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//div/a[contains(@class,"tag-link-1942 tag-link-position-3")]/@href'):
        url = href.extract()    
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item2)

    def parse_item2(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//div/article/header/h2/a/@href'):
            next_page_url = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "wp-pagenavi")]/a[contains(@class, "page larger")]/@href')
            if len(next_page_url):
                print(response.xpath('string(//h2[@class="entry-title"]/a)').extract())
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url.extract_first(), callback=self.parse_item2)
```